# Matrix, complex vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $M$ is a real 2 by 2 matrix with the property that $M^2+I=0$, and the eigenvalues of $M$ is $i$ and $-i$.

Prove that there exists a complex matrix P with the property that $$P^{-1}(aI+bM)P=\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b\\ b
 &a 
\end{bmatrix}$$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

I have some progress of this question, so I am not sure if this is correct $$P^{-1}(aI+bM)P=aP^{-1}IP+bP^{-1}MP=aI+bP^{-1}MP$$ ???? how do you show this?well, if that is correct, I some how want to show that $$P^{-1}MP$$ is the matrix \begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\1 
 &0 
\end{bmatrix}
then something about the two matrix are similar, I am thinking really hard, all of this now looks like a mess in my head, can someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: any ideas that can clear this a little?

Comment: okay, em...that is just em... I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$Q^{-1} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{:=J} Q = \begin{pmatrix} -i & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix} \quad \textrm{where } Q := \begin{pmatrix} -i & i \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and then, since there exists a complex matrix $R$ with $$R^{-1}MR = \begin{pmatrix} -i & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix}$$ we have $$QR^{-1}MRQ^{-1} = Q \begin{pmatrix} -i & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix} Q^{-1} = J.$$ Thus, for $P := RQ^{-1}$, $$P^{-1}(aI+bM)P = aI+bP^{-1}MP = aI + bJ = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How do you know Q is that matrix?

Comment: You mean how did I find it?

Comment: oh, I got it, you diagonalize that 0 -1 1 0 matrix, and the eigenvectors

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly established, what we're looking for is $P$ such that $PMP^{-1} = J$, where
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}.
$$
One standard approach to this is to use diagonalization over the complex numbers: because both $M$ and $J$ are diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\pm i$, they are similar to the same complex matrix and therefore similar to each other. This tells us that there is an invertible matrix $P$ with possibly complex entries for which $PMP^{-1} = J$.

Here is an approach which guarantees that $P$ is real. The operation $M\mapsto PMP^{-1}$ is a change of basis, so what we want to show is that there is a basis $\mathcal B = \{v_1,v_2\}$ such that the matrix of $M$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is $J$.

With that in mind, take $v_1$ to be any non-zero vector. I claim that $Mv_1$ and $v_1$ are linearly independent. Otherwise, $Mv_1$ would be a real vector that is a multiple of $v_1$, which would mean that $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to a real eigenvalue, which is impossible. Define $v_2 = Mv_1$. Note that
$$
Mv_2 = M(Mv_1) = M^2v_1 = (-I)v_1 = -v_1.
$$
Thus, we have $Mv_1 = 0\cdot v_1 + 1 \cdot v_2$, and $Mv_2 = -1 \cdot v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2$. It follows that the matrix $[M]_{\mathcal B}$ of $M$ with respect to $\mathcal B$ is $J$. Equivalently, if we take $P$ to be the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,$ then $PMP^{-1} = J$, which was what we wanted.

Comment: hi, you can't just say J is that matrix, how do you prove that it is actually the matrix that we want? and how do you prove that it is similar? you can't just say this fact right? how do you prove that it is similar?

Comment: @Logan As I said, it follows from the fact that $Mv_1 = v_2$ and $Mv_2= -v_1$.

Comment: yeah, I am unsure about your second way of doing it, but the first way is much more clear now to me. Thank you

Comment: @Logan I misread the question before. If I had noticed that $P$ is allowed to have complex entries, I would have stuck to the first method